# How do I prevent a Java Swing JTable column from being sorted when the user click on the header?

Tags: java, swing, sorting, jtable

I have a JTable that has several columns.  I wanted to make **some** of the columns unsortable.  How do I do it?  I am stuck using Java 1.4 so using TableRowSorter isn't an option since it wasn't introduced until 1.6.

Comment: If JTable made sortable yourself, I'm sure you will be able to figure out.

Comment: Do you want to stop only one column or all of them?

Answer (score 5):

- apply `RowSorter` to the desired column(s) only
- [replace in post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12271011/714968)

(for example, only pseudo_code, everything is there hardcoded as example, have to override columns from ColumnModel)

```
if (column >= 0 && column < getModelWrapper().getColumnCount() 
    && isSortable(column)) {
```

with

```
if (column >= 0 && column <=1  /*getModelWrapper().getColumnCount()*/ 
    && isSortable(column)) {
```

in `public void toggleSortOrder(int column) {`

then second column isn't sortable

- if not help you for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) demonstrated your issue

Answer (score 0):

Set the rowSorter on the JTable to null. See http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setRowSorter(javax.swing.RowSorter)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sort some and not others, you'll have to implement a listener. I've used something like this:

```
table.getTableHeader().addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            int col= table.getTableHeader().columnAtPoint(e.getPoint());
            // column number col has been clicked -- sort if necessary,
            // discard the event if sorting is not desired.
            //
        }

    });
```

Watch out for tables that can drag and drop rows; you can disable this with

```
table.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);
```

Comment: This does not work, you only add additional logic, but you do not prevent the existing mouselisteners and sorting logic to be applied... Tested like this:  


    table.getTableHeader().addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                return;
            }

        });

Comment: True it does not prevent existing listeners from firing. However, if you're using the BasicTableHeaderUI (as I expect most are), you can setReorderingAllowed to false (as indicated) and it will work.