# Disable Column Header sorting on a JTable

Tags: java, swing, sorting, jtable

Is it possible to disable manual sorting on a JTable after adding a sorter? So I have a JTable that has the following sorter attached to it (basically sorts by column 3 when the table is initialised):

```
JTable jTable = new JTable();
RowSorter<TableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<TableModel>(jTable.getModel());
List<RowSorter.SortKey> sortKeys = new ArrayList<RowSorter.SortKey>();
sortKeys.add(new RowSorter.SortKey(3, SortOrder.DESCENDING));
sorter.setSortKeys(sortKeys); 
jTable.setRowSorter(sorter);
```

This works fine, however the user is still able to click on the column headers in the table and sort by any of the columns, which I want to disable. Is this possible?

Comment: You might like to check @mkorbel's suggests from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14365510/how-do-i-prevent-a-java-swing-jtable-column-from-being-sorted-when-the-user-clic) similar questions

Comment: reading Default/RowSorter's api doc might help :-)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use the **setSortable** method of **TableRowSorter** as below:

```
sorter.setSortable(0, false);
```

to make column 0 non-sortable. You can apply it on the column according to your requirement.

Comment: `RowSorter#setSortable(int, boolean)` function does not exist. You might be referring to some other class that has it, but your answer doesn't reference that at all, which makes it a bad answer. Please update.

Comment: Technically it's more accurate to say `DefaultRowSorter#setSortable(int, boolean)`, but since TableRowSorter extends DefaultRowSorter, this answer is still valid.

Comment: `((DefaultRowSorter) jTable.getRowSorter()).setSortable(0, false);` would prevent column 0 from being sorted. As stated on the other comments `setSortable(int,bool)` belongs to `DefaultRowSorter`

Answer (score 6):

Alternatively, you can set your sortable and non-sortable columns like this:

```
TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<TableModel>(table.getModel()) {
    @Override
    public boolean isSortable(int column) {
        if(column < 2)
            return true;
        else 
            return false;
    };
};
table.setRowSorter(sorter);
```

Answer (score 6):

I ran into the same problem recently, and found the perfect solution to this problem. The `TableHeader` can simply be disabled.

```
jTable.getTableHeader().setEnabled(false);
```

This way, the **sorter** works perfectly on any of the columns, but **manual sorting** is prevented by click on the Column Headers.

Hope this helps the future users who might want to have a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

In case your table derived from com.jidesoft.grid.TreeTable (JIDE), you can do this:

```
 class MyTreeTable extends TreeTable
    {
        public MyTreeTable()
        {
            getSortableTableModel().setColumnSortable(0, false);
        }
    }
```

Note that getSortableTableModel is protected so it must be called from within a TreeTable method (constructor in this example).