# jTable disable sort on specific column

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-jtable

I am using jTable plugin for showing data in a MVC Application. I have set up table as below.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#StudentTableContainer').jtable({
        title: 'The Employee List',
        paging: true, //Enable paging
        pageSize: 10, //Set page size (default: 10)
        sorting: true, //Enable sorting
        defaultSorting: 'Name ASC', //Set default sorting
        actions: {
            listAction: '/Employee/Employees',
            deleteAction: '/Employee/Delete',
            updateAction: '/Employee/Edit', 
            createAction: '/Employee/Create'
        },
        fields: {
            Id: {
                key: true,
                create: false,
                edit: false,
                list: false
            },
            Name: {
                title: 'Name',
                width: '15%'
            },
            Age: {
                title: 'Age',
                width: '5%'
            },
            Position: {
                title: 'Post',
                options: 'Employee/GetJobPosts',
                width: '12%'
            },
            DownloadUrls: {
                title: 'Resume',
                width: '13%',
                display: function (data) {
                    if (data.record.DownloadUrls) {
                        var urls = data.record.DownloadUrls.split(',');
                        var html = '';
                        var li = '';
                        urls.forEach(function (entry) {
                            li = li + '<li><a href="' + entry + '" target="_blank" runat="server" download>' + entry.split('/').pop() + '</a></li>';
                        })
                        html = "<ul>" + li + "</ul>";
                        return html;
                    } else {
                        return 'Please edit and upload resume';
                    }
                },
                input: function (data) {
                    return '<input type="file" name="resume" id="resume" multiple/>'
                }
            }
        },
        formCreated: function (event, data) {
            console.log('adding multipart attribute')
            data.form.attr('enctype', 'multipart/form-data');
        }
    });

    //Load student list from server
    $('#StudentTableContainer').jtable('load');
});
```

Where `paging: true,` enables paging for the jTable and `sorting: true,` enables sorting for jTable. But as you can see the script above I have a file upload in 1 field. It shows download urls for the files uploaded in the record.

> So I do not want sorting to be enabled on only 1 field DownloadUrls. Other fields need to have sorting

I have seen [Disable Column Header sorting on a JTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20903136/disable-column-header-sorting-on-a-jtable) , but I am using .NET and jQuery not Java and Swing, so everything is managed in script only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disable sorting for a specific column with the `sorting` option. See the documentation [here](http://jtable.org/ApiReference/FieldOptions#fopt-sorting).

There is also a demo of it in action [here](http://www.jtable.org/demo/pagingandsorting) - have a look at the "Record date" column and its code.

```
DownloadUrls: {
    ...
    sorting: false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In `DownloadUrls` array please add

```
sorting: false //This column is not sortable!
```

It may fix your need.

Thanks.