# java Swing String.format misaligned values comming from jtable in pdf format

Tags: java, mysql, swing

I cannot make values stable if the name of item is long and the other is short name the output is misaligned

Table Generated Values
Values coming from table

Code String that sets the values:

```
String line = String.format("%-35s %2s %6s\n\n", Names, Quanti, Prices);
```

[image: Output File Is Scrambled]

Comment: Use a custom [renderer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer). Also, _quantum_ singular; _quanta_ plural.

Comment: Try this [`CurrencyFormatter`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38192710/230513); if you still have problems, please edit your question to include a [mcve] that shows your revised approach.