# Displaying Image in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, imageicon

I'm trying to display an Image into column No 25 of a JTable :- For that i wrote the below code :-

```
    jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(25).setCellRenderer(jTable1.getDefaultRenderer(ImageIcon.class));
  String query = "SELECT   name,type,supplier, department, manufacturer, model, serial_no, description, location, broker, dop, installation_date, expiring_date, retiring_date,warranty_info, icost, rcost, aarea, voltage, wattage, amperage, eline, capacity, plink, notes, adding_date, modification_date from assets where  company_code='" + ims.MainWindow.cc + "' and adding_date between '" + new java.sql.Date(df.parse(df.format(jXDatePicker1.getDate())).getTime()) + "' and '" + new java.sql.Date(df.parse(df.format(jXDatePicker2.getDate())).getTime()) + "'";
            System.out.println(query);
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
            int xx = 1;
             byte[] imagedata=null;
            ImageIcon format=null;
            java.awt.Image originalImage=null;
            java.awt.Image scaledImage=null;

            javax.swing.ImageIcon newIconImage=null;
            while (rs.next()) {
                if(rs.getBytes(24)!=null){
                imagedata=rs.getBytes(24);
                  format = new ImageIcon(imagedata);
                originalImage = format.getImage();
                scaledImage = originalImage.getScaledInstance(268, 200, java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
                newIconImage = new javax.swing.ImageIcon(scaledImage);
                }
                mod.addRow(new Object[]{xx, rs.getString(1), rs.getString(2), rs.getString(3), rs.getString(4), rs.getString(5), rs.getString(6), rs.getString(7), rs.getString(8), rs.getString(9), rs.getString(10), rs.getString(11), rs.getString(12), rs.getString(13), rs.getString(14), rs.getString(15), rs.getString(16), rs.getString(17), rs.getString(18), rs.getString(19), rs.getString(20), rs.getString(21), rs.getString(22), rs.getString(23), newIconImage, rs.getString(25), rs.getString(26), rs.getString(27)});
                xx++;
            }
```

When i run the frame containing the below code ,instead of showing an Icon in the Image column "javax.swing.ImageIcon@119537a" is being shown in the image column . Pls help

Comment: You might like to take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14793396/rendering-bufferedimage-in-jtable-cell which is a similar question.

Comment: it's the exact same instance, registered for both :-)

Comment: @kleopatra it was worth a try :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When i run the frame containing the below code ,instead of showing an
>   Icon in the Image column "javax.swing.ImageIcon@119537a" is being
>   shown in the image column .

- I think that have to set [proper ColumnClass](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12271011/714968) for [Icon/ImageIcons (in this case and only)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html)
- [JTable knows Icon/ImageIcons data type in the ColumnClass](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender), same as `String`, `Number`, `Boolean` and e.i.

Answer (score 4):

You can try changing the column number where you set the image icon renderer.
I.e try 24 in

```
jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(25).setCellRenderer(jTable1.getDefaultRenderer(ImageIcon.class));
```

I suspect the renderer is not changed for the column where you added the image icon.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change the column number to 24 instead of 25.

```
jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(24).setCellRenderer(jTable1.getDefaultRenderer(ImageIcon.class));
```