# Java-MouseClick Events On Jtable

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to open the image file whenever user double clicks on the selected row.
I tried this code but its not working.

```
tab = new JTable(rows, column);
tab.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
tab.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        if (e.getClickCount() == 2) {

            int selectedRow = tab.getSelectedRow();

            try {
                String file = rows[0][2];
                String path = "C:\\XX\\YYY\\Gallery\\" + file;
                JLabel fileLable = new JLabel();
                fileLable.setBounds(500, 600, 300, 300);
                fileLable.setIcon(new ImageIcon(path));
                pan.add(fileLable);
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Please describe what is not working. The file is not loaded ? Is an exception thrown ? The mouseClicked does not get invoked ?

Comment: tab.getSelectedRow() returning -1

Comment: you may refer the below link, hope you would find what you need.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14829005/displaying-image-in-jtable

Comment: @Raj if for some reasons `tab.getSelectedRow()` returning -1 you can try `tab.rowAtPoint(e.getPoint());`. But I think, you have another problem, because the method `getSelectedRow()` in your case should also return a correct value.

Comment: Oh thank you now its working(using rowAtPoint(e.getPoint())).Do no how.