# JTable: text and image in the same column

Tags: java, image, swing, text, jtable

How to make JTable column which contains different types of data? (some cells contain images, some cells contain text)

Like this:

[image]

I tried to make CellRenderer but it doesn't work.

```
col.setCellRenderer(new DefaultTableCellRenderer() {
    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        if (value instanceof ImageIcon) {
            ImageIcon img = (ImageIcon) value;
            setIcon(img);
            setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        }
        else {
            setValue(value);
        }
        return this;
    }
});
```

It gives me this strange output:

[image]

Without renderer it outputs text and numbers fine but doesn't display images:

[image]

Comment: "*JTable: text and image in the same column"* Use a [`JLabel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html) as a [rendering component](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer).  The label supports both `ImageIcon` & text.

Comment: no idea how is that possible, there are three ways, everyhhing depends of settings in your XxxTableModel

Comment: JTable has a default renderer for ImageIcon, if you cast it correctly, it should work.

Comment: Show us a snippet of your code where you add the ImageIcon to the table.(the row/column containing it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- last screen_shots talking about `ColumnClass` isn't set correctly or isn't already set
- overrided `getColumnClass` with [`Icon/ImageIcon.Class`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12271011/714968) in `XxxTabelModel`,
- then your `Renderer` is seems like as useless

Comment: getColumnClass? I want to make column with different data types (text, images) not one column with images and another with text.

Comment: yes no issue is possible two ways, 1) easiest to setIcon in Renderer by (for example) String value stored in XxxTableModel for this cell 2. Renderer/Editor aren't about Column, but about [Cell in Column](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16971334/714968), this is your (maybe by mistake) decision

Comment: notice don't forget convert View to Model for both a.m. ways in my last comment

Answer (score 2):

JTable has a default renderer to render ImageIcon.

More about this here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender